# Liferay 6 / jBoss is there an 'easy' way to have clean urls?

Tags: jboss, portlet, liferay, coldfusion-9, clean-urls

I am working with Coldfusion 9, running under jBoss/Liferay 6.

All is well, I have developed quite a few portlets that I have made work around for (when I run into some issues that I could usually handle in a straight forward fashion). Overall Coldfusion 9 portlets work very well inside of Liferay.

One thing I really dislike is that the URLs are so unreadable, and I was really hoping for clean urls for my application, so when a user searches, and the result comes back, I can have them click a link like `http://liferaysite.com/web/viewitem/ABC123`.

Currently I get a raggedy URL that includes portlet status, properties, the portlet ID associated with the variable that I am passing (usually a combination of portlet id + variable) and other garbage that is un-needed.

Is there any 'easy' way to get clean URLs?  My issue is that I am not a JAVA person, so I am not too confidant in digging into jBoss/Liferay code to get something done. However I feel that Liferay is sufficiently 'hands-free' so that I can build my portlets and deploy them without modifying JAVA code and getting dirty.

Any ideas? I am not able to find many articles on this, especially since Liferay 6 is so new, and there are so few people posting things about it.  Maybe this would be some sort of URL rewriting in Jboss?

Thank you, appreciate any and all suggestions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is to use URL rewriting to achieve this and transform Liferay URLs to any form you want. There are 2 possibilities I see to do this:

1. Put an Apache web server in front of your Liferay server and use mod_rewrite
2. Use the [URL rewriting filter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) that is already included in Liferay as this mimics what mod_rewrite does without the requirement of an extra Apache server

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in FriendlyUrlMappers. See [this blog entry](http://www.devatwork.nl/2010/04/seo-friendly-urls-for-liferay-portlets/) about the basics.

Regarding the "easy" you have to judge about that yourself. The nature of portals, e.g. combining completely different and independent applications (portlets) on a single page bring with it that you loose control over URLs (by default), because the portal has to disambiguate quite a lot of stuff. In order to get back control, you need to do some work, FriendlyUrlMappers impose some work, but the result is worth it IMHO.